# Python for loop Palindrome indexing compare -x in for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing

is there not a way to make this work in python, to compare or compute if a string is a palindrome
i know why it doesn't work, but is there some python magic to make python read the other side of the index like -1(end to start) instead of 1(start to end)

```
 for x in string:
    if x == -x:return True
```

am not looking for slicing / reversing the string using function and then comparing !

Comment: `string == string[::-1]` ?

Comment: sorry am not looking to reverse the string and compare but swing x around to the end

Answer (score 1):

Use string slicing:

```py
if string == string[::-1]:
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings don't support the minus operator but you can use subscripting to obtain what you're looking for:

```
if x == x[::-1]:  ...
```

Comment: yes , but x refers to a range in  for-loop so it there not away to x to start at the end of the range i want to take x and make it -(x)

Answer (score 0):

```
    if str(string)[::-1] == str(string):
    return True
```